# Question about finding the number of lists without repetition, and starting and ending with vowels

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question:

The problem consists of the letters: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.

How many length-5 lists can be made from these letters if repetition is not allowed, and the list must begin and end with a vowel?

NOTE: I know how to do the question, I just want to know if the way I did it is the correct way to do it. My answer matches the textbook's answer but steps are strikingly different.

From the question there are six types of lists:

```
    Starting with, Ending with
```

List 1:  A, E

List 2:  A, I

List 3:  E, A

List 4:  E, I

List 5:  I, A

List 6:  I, E

From the list, would this be how you solve the question? (Could I rearrange stuff from the list to match the description of "starting with, ending with?")

NOTE: from how I do it, if the letter is in round brackets, it is going to be removed from the list, and if in square brackets, it is going to be removed a second time.

List 1: (A), B, C, D, F, G, H, I, J, (E) ------    10 - A - E=8 Choices

List 2: (A), B, C, D, [E], F, G, H, J, (I) ----- 10 - A - E - I= 7 Choices

List 3: doesn’t count; same as list 1 (repetition)

List 4: (E), [A], B, C, D, [E], F, G, H, J, (I)-----6 Choices

List 5: doesn’t count; same as list 2 (repetition)

List 6: doesn’t count; same as list 4 (repetition)

Answer would be using the rule of product: number of lists x number of choices
= 6 x (8x7x6)

The answer above is the same as the textbook's answer, but they state it very differently or use different methods. Do you guys think how I did it is the right way to do it? or is it just a coincidence that I got the same answer??

Comment: From the textbook, it says " For lists starting with "A" and ending with "E" the choices for positions 2,3,4 are 8,7,6 respectively." Why did the textbook skip positions 1 and immediately go to positions 2?? If you remove letters A and E from position 1, why does that make it to position 2??

Answer (score 1):

You did this correctly ... though maybe a bit long-windedly.

But yes, the basic approach is: you have 3 vowels, so you have 3 options for the starting letter, and therefore 2 left for the ending one, so that's 6 options there.

Then, out of the remaining 8 letters, you have 8 options for the second letter, and thus 7 options left for the third, and therefore 6 options left for the fourth letter.

Total: 6x8x7x6

Comment: Just to be clear, does position 2, or whatever position mean list? Are terms "position" and "list" interchangeable? And what does repetition mean? Does it mean that the list repeats or the letters repeat or both?

Comment: @derekingo 'position' is position of the letter in the list. So, for example, in the list ABCDE, the C is in position 3

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but my textbook says " For lists starting with "A" and ending with "E" the choices for positions 2,3,4 are 8,7,6 respectively." Which corresponds to the lists perfectly, because list 2 has 8 choices, list 3 has 7 and list 4 has 6. Do you know what the textbook means by this?

Comment: @derekingo That's exactly what I say in my Answer as well: once the first and last (fifth) letter are determined, you have 8 options for position 2, 7 options for position 3, and 6 options for position 4

Comment: could you show what you mean by after having A and E determined, 8 options for position 2, 7 options for position 3 and so on? I know having A and E removed gives 8 options but why particularly position 2 has 8 options

Comment: @derekingo Well, the assumption is that, after you have used two letters for psoitions 1 and 5, the *next* position you fill is position 2. So that gives 8 options for position 2. And then, *after* you have filled position 2, you fill position 3, so that leaves 7 options for position 3. And then finally you do position 4, so 6 options left for that one.  Of course, we could also have done position 4 first, and then position 3, and then position 2. So then you would have had 8 options for position 4, 7 options for position 3, and 6 options for position 2. Either way, you get 8x7x6

Comment: ah makes much more sense now. By the way, is the "way" I did the question from above correct? I know you said it is, but considering the rules of sum and product and counting rules, would it be appropriate to do it my way? Thanks.

Comment: @derekingo Yes, you really did that correctly!